# How can I change the font style of function calls but not declarations for a specific language in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

For example, does anyone know how to italicize function calls like this in VS Code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the scope inspector tool (`Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`) to find out info about the semantic tokens of something (or the TextMate scopes).

With the semantic tokens approach, do it like this:

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "rules": {
        "function:javascript": { // italicize functions
            "italic": true
        },
        "function.declaration:javascript": { // but don't italicize their declarations
            "italic": false
        }
    }
},
```

See also the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#semantic-coloring-in-color-themes.

---

I couldn't figure out how to do with with the TextMate approach.

The TextMate scopes on function calls:

```
entity.name.function.js
meta.function-call.js
source.js
```

I couldn't get something to work for just function calls. I think it has to do with how [match ranking works in TextMate selctors](https://macromates.com/manual/en/scope_selectors#ranking_matches). Probably a builtin textmateRule is already matching against `entity.name.function.js`, which makes it difficult (impossible?) to match against `meta.function-call.js` in a way that overrides the one on `entity.name.function.js`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes, and the semanticTokenColorCustomizations worked for me